# Using existing codebuild.json with cdk

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

To create codebuild/codepipeline project and ECS task definition, I have existing codebuild.json, codepipeline.json and task_definition.json which work with aws CLI perfectly.

Is there a way that I can use these JSON files with CDK, so that instead of using CLI, I can use CDK for deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AWSCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct, which is perfect for creating resources using the AWS CLI instead of CF. Also see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html#custom-resources-for-aws-apis) including some examples.

As parameters to the custom resources, you can then provide the contents of your json files.